# Retrieving VUI after AVC/HEVC decoding from *.yuv file?

Tags: video-processing, yuv, libavcodec, hevc

Background:
Video usability information (VUI) is extra information that can be inserted into an AVC (h.264) or HEVC (h.265) video bitstream. The documents defining AVC and HEVC specify that an AVC/HEVC-decoder retrieves this information. Reference software of AVC and HEVC en- and decoders can be found here [1], [2].

My question:
Where is VUI stored after AVC/HEVC-decoding? Is it stored within the output file *.yuv?

I am very grateful for any advice.

[1] https://vcgit.hhi.fraunhofer.de/jvet/JM
[2] https://vcgit.hhi.fraunhofer.de/jvet/HM

I investigated the AVC [1] and HEVC [2] reference software, but I after decoding VUI from the bitstream, I loose track what happens to VUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YUV is a raw **pixel** format. Meaning that there is absolutely no information other than the pixels' intensity values in it.

If you want your VUI data:

- Pre-save the FPS elsewhere and/or use a custom delay (FPS) during the decoding process.
- Write your YUV data into a formats that supports timing info (*eg:* `.y4m` format).